# Cookie Issue with FormsAuthentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, razor

i have two websites with FormsAuthentication which are installed on the same machine. Now if i use firebug and firecookie i can see that the applications receive both cookies the own AuthenticationCookie and the Cookie from the other one.
The cookies have different names.
Application 1:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" name=".Cookie1" />
</authentication>
```

Application 2:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" name=".Cookie2" />
</authentication>
```

Is there any reason for this behavior?

Regards

Comment: Yes, it is on localhost and also on a Virtual Machine. On both, the Sites are Virtual Directories under the Default WeSite.

Comment: if I understand you want each application to only have its cookie?

Comment: Yes the ".Cookie1" should not be sent to Application2 and ".Cookie2" not to Application1.

Comment: if I did answer your question you can mark it so :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that since both application run on localhost the Host of both cookies is most probably the same (localhost).

A possible solution would be to set the `domain` and `name` in the web.config file as per [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx)

There is also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5222254/168097) on stackoverflow